# How to disable smiley key and specific symbols in android soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I want to know whether it is possible to disable few keys of andriod soft keyboard like the smiley symbol and few symbols and keyboard setting option.I want to restrict user from using these keys.Kindly help

Comment: did you get solution for this issue?

Comment: No not yet i hope i will get it soon.